# Missing focus cursor on input field hybrid android cordova webview

Tags: android, cordova, webview

We have android hybrid app with Cordova where are creating custom inappbrowser with cordova webview to show the content. In Android lollipop devices, when user selects input field, keyboard pops up and user can enter test but there is no curser in the input field. This is not happening in pre lollipop. I tried below options, also this happens sporadically, i am getting focus sometimes but most times it is not working

```
inAppWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
inAppWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUSABLES_TOUCH_MODE);
```

or

```
inAppWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUSABLES_ALL);
```

or

```
inAppWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

or

```
inAppWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                                v.requestFocus();
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Same here. Funny thing is, this only occurs inside our Cordova App, when we access the same source from the browser on the phone, it works just fine and the caret appears.

Answer (score 1):

Though now probably seomewhat outdated, the solution can be found at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11248

Basically, you need to change onPageFinished to

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
  super.onPageFinished(view, url);
  view.clearFocus();
  view.requestFocus();
```

}

Comment: The problem is stil existing in version 1.6.4

Comment: It's working till now.

Answer (score 0):

After quite some thinking and effort looking through the repo history, we finally nailed it down & fixed it.

While initializing a plugin we did perform some javascript on the WebView. We we're using **'evaluateJavascript'** to perform the javascript (this does work on Lollipop, not on KitKat btw), but that somehow had the side-effect of making the caret disappear. After using **'loadUrl'** instead, it did work again.

In the javascript we did add a custom attribute (HD_APP) to the window, so nothing that should cause such a side effect. As you can see in the screenshot, the input was no longer identified with ":focus" by css.

Hope this helps..

[image: comparison of the input css of a working example (left) and the one without a caret (right)]

Answer (score 0):

The thing that caused the issue for me is that I called `evaluateJavascript` before I had any page loaded.

After I made sure that my page was ready for JS before sending any, the issue disappeared.